# ArcGIS Pro hangs after running script

Tags: arcgis-pro, python-window

I am using ArcGIS Pro v2.8.3 and am using the Python window to run a few short scripts I have written. The scripts complete as normal, and I am able to use the Python window to do other things. However the blue mouse wheel spins whenever I hang over the Python window, and I am not able to do most other tasks in ArcGIS Pro. Most of the ribbon is grayed out on every tab. I am able to use the Python window, for example to print a variable that was set at the end of the script, or to do something totally different. Waiting does not help; this seems to continue indefinitely.

The scripts can be as simple as 'import os' or a simple call to a geoprocessing tool.

Is there any way to get the Python window to 'release' this hang short of restarting ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: No one can answer this question unless you share your script that is cause the problem, if that indeed is the source.

Comment: You forgot to post the script.  Please edit your question (using the 'Edit' link at the bottom of the question) and post the script.  Preferably post the shortest possible version of the script that still causes the problem.

Comment: I didn't include the specific script because it affects multiple scripts, which are unrelated. Even the most simple commands such as importing a base package or calling a geoprocessing tool can cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My python environment was partially broken. In short, I was using a clone of the default python environment to which I had installed a few additional packages. Although the packages are widely used and accepted, and I did use conda to install them, I somehow ended up with an environment with limited functionality.

To solve the hanging issue, I simply switched environments back to the default python environment. I still use the partially broken environment to run scripts which require the packages only it has, but whenever I need to do anything else in Pro, I just switch back to the default environment.